# How to check single class parameter from document.querySelectorAll?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Can someone explain to me how to use if else statement for single class, when I have more than one class as selectors in `querySelectorAll`? For example I have

```js
var x = document.querySelectorAll(".clickMapItem.text , .clickMapItem.multiImageText");

for (i = 0; i < click_map_items.length; i++) {
  click_map_items[i].style.display = "none";
}
```

```html
<div id="one" class="clickMapItem text" style="display: none;"></div>
<div id="two" class="clickMapItem text" style="display: none;"></div>
<div id="three" class="clickMapItem multiImageText" style="display: none;"></div>
<div id="four" class="clickMapItem text" style="display: none;"></div>
<div id="five" class="clickMapItem multiImageText" style="display: none;"></div>
```

I want to check that all divs with class `.clickMapItem.text` is display none, but for second class check if it is display block.

I tried to do with `if (x[0].style.display == "none") { code here }` 
but it takes only the first `div` from the `NodeList`, and I want to check all.

What about `Array.prototype.slice.call` parameter or something else?

Answer (score 3):

Iterate all `clickMapItem` using `querySelectorAll()`. While iterating, you can use [`classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) property and its `contains()` method to check wheather the element has a class.

```js
var click_map_items = document.querySelectorAll(".clickMapItem");
for (i = 0; i < click_map_items.length; i++) {
  var elem = click_map_items[i];
  
  if (elem.classList.contains('text'))
    elem.style.display = "none";
  
  if (elem.classList.contains('multiImageText'))
    elem.style.display = "block";
}
```

---

However you can implement same fuunctionality using Pure CSS rules

```css
.clickMapItem.text {
  display: none;
}
.clickMapItem.multiImageText {
  display: block;
}
```

Comment: Ok, but instead click_map_items.length should be x.length? Right? This part of the code that you sent me is good, like what I was looking for, but also I need some changes. Please take a look what I am trying to do - https://jsfiddle.net/d0xyqbj7) because in this case does not work very well, because onclick when contains 'text' , 'clickMapFlashContainer' also disappears, and should not be as you can see in my jsfiddle, should disappear only when contains 'multiImageText'

Comment: @MileMijatovic, It was an example you can certainly use `else` like https://jsfiddle.net/d0xyqbj7/1/

Comment: Ok, but what is happening now, https://jsfiddle.net/fcu9vcf2/ - both of the if statement are executed, console.log(elem) - http://prntscr.com/d43xab ... should concern only one div, but in this case applies to all

Comment: @Saptal, can you help me? What should I do? Should check only for a single div whether there is a class 'text' or 'multiimagetext', in this case checks all at once

Comment: @MileMijatovic, You can use simple conditions `elem.classList.contains("text") || elem.classList.contains("multiImageText")` these are logical issue which you need to resolve as per your requirement

Comment: @Saptal, I am not sure, because if I would use | | I would have both conditions in one if, but should be separated as you know... is there any other way?

Answer (score 0):

You can use normal css selectors for this.
Please have a look at this --> 
    http://jsfiddle.net/5tSGv/12/

```
var classOne = document.querySelectorAll( '.class1:not(.class2)' );
for( var i = 0; i < classOne.length; i++ ) {
    classOne[i].style.backgroundColor="#f3f3f3";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the final version of how it should look like

```js
 < script >
   function changeStyle(hotspotid) {
     var hotspot = hotspotid.replace('_clickable', '');
     var x = document.getElementById(hotspot);
     click_map_items = document.querySelectorAll(".clickMapItem");
     for (i = 0; i < click_map_items.length; i++) {
       var elem = click_map_items[i];

       elem.style.display = "none";

       if (elem.classList.contains('text')) {
         document.getElementById("clickMap_item_default").style.display = "none";
         x.style.display = "block";
       };

       if (x.classList.contains('multiImageText')) {
         document.getElementById('clickMapFlashContainer').style.display = "none";

       };
     };
   };

 function backClose() {
   for (i = 0; i < click_map_items.length; i++) {
     click_map_items[i].style.display = "none";
   }
   document.getElementById('clickMapFlashContainer').style.display = "";
   document.getElementById("clickMap_item_default").style.display = "";
 }; 

< /script>
```